# anchor to post ID Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Guys to make my modal dynamic and show different contents between different posts I need to anchor the id of the post.

These are the data I need to replace:

```
modal6
```

and

```
#modal6
```

code:

```
  <!--Modal: Name-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

            <!--Content-->
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!--Body-->
                <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">

                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-1-half">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" allowfullscreen src="<?php echo $AMC_metakey_video; ?>"></iframe>
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>
            <!--/.Content-->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal: Name-->
    <a>
    <img class="card-img-top" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal6" <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
```

if i could put the `get_the_ID()` i can fix my problem.
i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
<!--Modal: Name-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal<?= get_the_ID() ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

            <!--Content-->
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!--Body-->
                <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">

                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-1-half">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" allowfullscreen src="<?php echo $AMC_metakey_video; ?>"></iframe>
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>
            <!--/.Content-->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal: Name-->
    <a>
    <img class="card-img-top" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal<?= get_the_ID() ?>" <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
```

Hope it helps.